# Same affiliation for multiple authors using achemso

Tags: author, affiliation, achemso, authblk

I would like to assign the same affiliation for multiple authors using the `achemso` document class. I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Notitle}

\author[1]{Noname1}
\author[1]{Noname2}
\author[2]{Noname3}
\author[1,2,3]{Noname4}

\affil[1]{Nowhere1}
\affil[2]{Nowhere2}
\affil[3]{Nowhere3}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Could you please help to make this code correct?

Comment: Why not use the build in interface for it instead of trying to use `authblk`, `achemso` does have a fine manual, see for example page 4 in said manual